# How bigger jQuery projects are structured and what the reasons for that

Tags: javascript, jquery, architecture

I'm developing Desktop-Software with different OO-based languages. I haven't got in touch with web development since recently. I just started playing around with `jQuery` and `jQuery Mobile` to build simple web applications.

I noticed that my projects usually end up with a HTML-file as a base and a *.js file which contains the methods, eventhandlers etc. This somewhat feels like programming spaghetti code and I can't think of how this could work with more complex projects. (Reusability, Performance, ...)

Usual jQuery-Tutorials are just showing trivial examples which work well with the "all methods into a single script-file"-approach. I also read somewhere, that it is better to provide just a big file because it is faster to load just one file instead of a lot small files.

Can someone tell me how bigger jQuery-projects are structured and what the reasons for that are?

Comment: Actually, many large projects consist of multiple source files that are minified and concatenated into one file for distribution.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly valid question and it doesn't deserve the downvotes. What it deserves is a better title through.

Comment: @rcdmk: Thanks for your contribution. It often is hard to find the right words for the question-title. I often notice how the title would fit better AFTER the question has been answered (and by that my thoughts on the problem have gone through some iterations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to break up your question into smaller parts:

**"I noticed that my projects usually end up with a HTML-file as a base and a *.js file which contains the methods, eventhandlers etc. This somewhat feels like programming spaghetti code and I can't think of how this could work with more complex projects."**

Sounds like your OO background has you spoiled. Javascript won't force you to use it's prototypal inheritance, and neither will jQuery. Nevertheless, *it is there*. Douglas Crockford wrote a piece about moving from a classical OO-centric inheritance to the prototypal equivalent: [Prototypal Inheritance in Javascript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)

**"Usual jQuery-Tutorials are just showing trivial examples which work well with the "all methods into a single script-file"-approach."**

Yes, putting all your code in one file will work fine for a small website or web-app, but it doesn't scale.

However this is no difference from putting all your C method declarations in one header and all the code in one source file. My point being that you don't have too.

I'd recommend you look at a script loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) as a solution to this problem. In worst case there's still nothing wrong with putting your script tags inline in your HTML code but this also doesn't scale well.

**"I also read somewhere, that it is better to provide just a big file because it is faster to load just one file instead of a lot small files."**

Well ... yes, but this is negligible in most cases. Even if you do see a drop in performance, why treat your development code as your production? Use a compression tool such as [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.com/yuicompressor/) to compress and merge your JavaScript. Smaller load times without the  pollution.

Final piece of advice: jQuery is not going to help you solve your JavaScript architecture problems any more than a dictionary will help you structure a sentence. (In other words, don't rely on jQuery examples to teach you good JavaScript practices).

Comment: +1 For "don't rely on jQuery examples to teach you good JavaScript practices"

Comment: This clearifies a lot. Thanks for the links, I'm currently reading